# How can we abbreviate a reference?

Tags: git

I heard that, in Git, we can use either a full ref name or its abbreviation.

How can we abbreviate a reference `ref`, for example, in the following cases?

```
.git/ref
.git/refs/ref
.git/refs/tags/ref
.git/refs/heads/ref
.git/refs/remotes/ref
.git/refs/remotes/ref/HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, most references in Git live under the `refs/` namespace: so `refs/heads/master` is the branch `master`, `refs/tags/v1.0.0` is the tag `v1.0.0`, and `refs/remotes/origin/master` is the remote tracking branch for `master` on the remote `origin`. All of these are full references.

When you type something like `git checkout master`, you're abbreviating the reference: Git will try to resolve it to the proper location (which in this case, is usually a branch).

The way to get Git to do this for you is to use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref`. For example, in my copy of Git, I get the following:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref refs/heads/master
master
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref refs/remotes/origin/master
origin/master
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref refs/tags/v1.0.0
v1.0.0
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
master
```

The final case, incidentally, is the best way to ask “what branch am I on?”.

You can also use a short name with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref`, as in the following:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref v1.0.0
v1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem) tells you in the section `<refname>`:

```
   <refname>, e.g. master, heads/master, refs/heads/master
       A symbolic ref name. E.g.  master typically means the commit object
       referenced by refs/heads/master. If you happen to have both
       heads/master and tags/master, you can explicitly say heads/master
       to tell Git which one you mean. When ambiguous, a <refname> is
       disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:

        1. If $GIT_DIR/<refname> exists, that is what you mean (this is
           usually useful only for HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, MERGE_HEAD
           and CHERRY_PICK_HEAD);

        2. otherwise, refs/<refname> if it exists;

        3. otherwise, refs/tags/<refname> if it exists;

        4. otherwise, refs/heads/<refname> if it exists;

        5. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname> if it exists;

        6. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD if it exists.

           HEAD names the commit on which you based the changes in the
           working tree.  FETCH_HEAD records the branch which you fetched
           from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation.
           ORIG_HEAD is created by commands that move your HEAD in a
           drastic way, to record the position of the HEAD before their
           operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch
           back to the state before you ran them.  MERGE_HEAD records the
           commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run
           git merge.  CHERRY_PICK_HEAD records the commit which you are
           cherry-picking when you run git cherry-pick.

           Note that any of the refs/* cases above may come either from
           the $GIT_DIR/refs directory or from the $GIT_DIR/packed-refs
           file. While the ref name encoding is unspecified, UTF-8 is
           preferred as some output processing may assume ref names in
           UTF-8.
```